# Finding how many times I need to perform an action before I have an x% chance of a specific outcome in r

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution

Non-specific question: There is an action that can be performed that has multiple outcomes. Each outcome has a different probably, p, of occurring. How many times, n, do I need to do the action before I have an x% chance of a specific outcome occurring one or more times.

I know in r I can do this and change n until I get the x I'm looking for:

```
1-dbinom(0, n, p)
```

and that will show me the probability of the action occurring one or more times. What would be the inverse where I say function(x, n, p)?

Specific question: There is a slot machine. A specific outcome happens 0.02% of the time. How many times would someone spin the slots before they have a 90% chance of that outcome occurring one or more times?

Comment: Hint: $P(\text{at least once in}~n~\text{tries}) = 1-P(\text{never in}~n~ \text{tries})=(1-(1-p)^n)$. Can you think of any way of solving $$0.9 = 1 - (1-0.0002)^n$$ for $n$? Logarithms might help in some way...

Comment: Thank you for the mathematics behind it! In this case n would equal 11511.8. However, I'm more looking for the r function that handles this. qbinom is the inverse of pbinom, but it still doesn't find n, instead n is a parameter of the the function. By the way, no this isn't for homework. I'm interested in solving this for a video game.

Comment: Someone edited my question to add the negative-binomal tag. After searching for solving for those in r, I was able to found the correct function I needed! I appreciate showing the math behind it so I know what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the r function I was looking for:

Using the numbers from the question above

```
qnbinom(0.9, 1, 0.0002)
```